# how to show bottom of a long div which position is fixed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my page, left div position is fixed after some scrolling. The problem is if the left div content is higher than window, then the lower part of the div is not showing. My code snippet is like following:

```
var offesttop_menupanel = $('#menu-list').offset().top;
if($(this).scrollTop() > offesttop_menupanel)
{
   $('#menu-list').addClass('fixed-menu');
   $("#menu-list").css("width", menu_div_width);
}
else
{
   $('#menu-list').removeClass('fixed-menu');
}
 #### CSS ####
.fixed-menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 30px;  
}
```

Here is jsfiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/karim_fci/z68qhLpf/4/).

How can i show lower part of the div in this situation without using scrollbar?

Comment: `height: nnpx; overflow-y: auto`

Comment: add the HTML too. a jsfiddle demo will be best.

Comment: and define width too.

Comment: keep an over flow as the content cannot be adjusted in sceen

Comment: I would contemplate the KISS principle here. Don't make it fixed.

Comment: JS fiddle link added @Rejith R Krishnan

Comment: height: nnpx; overflow-y: auto; this add scroll bar. i don't want scroll bar. @ Tushar

Comment: @karim_fci The problem is we don't know what you want. What would a possible solution do that would satisfy you? Either the div is fixed and it has a scrollbar, or the div is not fixed and scrolls with the page, or... what? Do you want to scale it down to the height of the window, with smaller texts?